# Cannot run Grails CLI: Grails CLI: Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch

Tags: grails

Trying to run a Groovy/Grails application in NetBeans I got the following error message:

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch
```

Grails version: 3.0.4
Java: jdk1.8.0_20

Comment: You may also try to upgrade your JVM to the latest version. There are some bugs in older versions such as this and with spring loaded. RE: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10132#issuecomment-244295268

Answer (score 7, accepted):

setting the `GRAILS_OPTS` environment variable to `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Xverify:none` fixes the issue